# Azure Machin Learing - How to train with very limited dataset

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, anomaly-detection

I am a beginner and I need some advice on how to go about modelling the below scenario
I am consuming ~5000 rows of data on an average from an external system everyday. The number of incoming rows are between 4950 to 5050. I want to build an alerting mechanism which would tell me if the number of incoming rows is not normal. i.e., I want a solution to let me know if I get say, 2500 rows on a given day which is 50% less or say 15000 rows which way more than the average.
Sample data as below: 
| Day | Size of incoming data (in MB) | Number of Rows | Label | 
| Weekday | 3.44 | 5000 | Y | 
| Weekday | 3.3 | 4999 | Y | 
| Weekday | 3.1 | 4955 | Y | 
| Weekday | 3.44 | 5000 | Y | 
| Weekend | 4.1 | 5050 | N | 
My initial thought was to use some anomaly detection algorithm. I tried using the Principal Component Analysis algorithm to detect the anomaly. I had collected the total number of rows I receive everyday and used it for training the model. But, after training with the data I had, which is quite limited (less than 500 observations) I find that the accuracy is very poor. One-Class SVM also did not give me good result.
I had used "Number of rows" as Categorical Feature, Label as.. label and ignore the rest of the parameters as they are of no interest to me in this case. Irrespective of day and size of incoming data my logic revolves around the number of rows only.
Also, I don't have any negative scenario so far, meaning, I never received far too less or far too many records. So I labeled all days when I received 5050 rows as anomalous. The rest I labeled as normal.
I do realize that I am doing something fundamentally wrong here. The question is, does my scenario even qualify for usage on machine learning? (I believe it does, but wanted your opinion)
If yes, how to deal with such limited set of training data where you hardly have any sample anomaly. And is it really an anomaly problem or can I just use some classification algorithm to get better result?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the time-series anomaly detection module. it should do what you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/96b98cc0-50df-46ff-bc18-c0665d69f3e3?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks very much Hai Ning, this fits my purpose. I will update you on how it goes.